# npm run server error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: angular, windows, npm

I came across this issue while running this project from github https://github.com/angular-university/reactive-angular-course. I am running on windows and have all the latest dependencies, still I am facing this issue, however on mac it is working fine. Can anyone please help me with that?

```
$ npm run server

> reactive-angular-course@0.0.0 server
> ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -P ./server/server.tsconfig.json ./server/server.ts

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Windows machine. Adding the full paths to the start and server scripts in `package.json` resolved the issue for me. E.g.,

```
"start": "C:\\\dev\\\reactive-angular-course\\\node_modules\\\\.bin\\\ng serve  --proxy-config C:\\\dev\\\reactive-angular-course\\\proxy.json",<br>
"server": "C:\\\dev\\\reactive-angular-course\\\node_modules\\\\.bin\\\ts-node -P C:\\\dev\\\reactive-angular-course\\\server\\\server.tsconfig.json C:\\\dev\\\reactive-angular-course\\\server\\\server.ts",
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the full path in `package.json` as suggested by @MrMiyagi2201 works.
I've implemented the below changes.

```
"start": "F:\\reactive\\reactive-angular-course\\node_modules\\.bin\\ng serve  --proxy-config F:\\reactive\\reactive-angular-course\\proxy.json",
"server": "F:\\reactive\\reactive-angular-course\\node_modules\\.bin\\ts-node -P F:\\reactive\\reactive-angular-course\\server\\server.tsconfig.json F:\\reactive\\reactive-angular-course\\server\\server.ts",
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30644812)